# Facebook Graph API: cannot retrieve non-friend's public posts from a friend's feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've crated a facebook application which retieves posts from my friends feeds by using https://graph.facebook.com/uid/feed.

The Access Token I use is an application access token with the following permissions:
friends_status, read_stream, user_status.

I noticed that the result does not contain public posts (from non-friends) shared by my friend and appear on his Timeline (when browsing).

Comment: This is the kind of posts I need to retrieve: http://i39.tinypic.com/20i8cqw.png

Comment: Did you find an answer to this in the end?